# Look at each character in a string

Tags: c#, string, search, character

I was wondering if anyone knew how to look through a string at each character and then add each character to a new string? Just a really really basic example, I can add the `ToUpper` and `ToLower` validation and such.

Comment: I'm sure you're just after the mechanics of your question and probably not the output, but since strings are immutable, your output is the same simply with assignment:  `string source = "foo"; string copy = source;`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
string foo = "hello world", bar = string.Empty;

foreach(char c in foo){
    bar += c;
}
```

---

Using `StringBuilder`:

```
string foo = "hello world";
StringBuilder bar = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char c in foo)
{
    bar.Append(c);
}
```

---

Below is the signature of the `String` `class`:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public sealed class String : IComparable, 
    ICloneable, IConvertible, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, 
    IEnumerable, IEquatable<string>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't want to do this with large strings as performance will be horrible.

Comment: @ChaosPandion agreed, `StringBuilder` is ideal for significant amounts of concatenations ...

Comment: or better use array (you can go back/forth inspect where needed too), IndexOf if you need to search, string constructor if you know the final array size...

Comment: @NSGaga a string already is and exposes an iterator ... try doing `foo[5]`

Comment: what I'm saying exactly - don't enumerate use [] etc. we misunderstood

Answer (score 5):

```
var output = ""; // or use StringBuilder
foreach(char c in text)
{
     output += c; // if or do with c what you need
}
```

...is that what you needed?
string is `IEnumerable<char>`